# Breaking up a packed int value and splitting it up into two components c++

Tags: c++

Without using any STL library function, can anyone kindly explain to me how to take a big int, lets say 288895 into something like 2888 and 95? I have trouble thinking of a proper solution.

For Example 288895 could be used to store both the employee number and the score employee got as his rating. I want it to be split into 2888 for student number and 95 for the exam.

Edit* I have thought of separating this into a string, using

```
substr(1,4)
```

in order to recreate a new string for the first part and using substr() again to recreate the string for the second part. Then I would return the function using these strings, I wonder if that was a viable option to apart from using the % operator like the comments suggested...

Thank You.

Comment: so always last 2 digits are representing score?

Comment: @moghya in this case, yes

Comment: or maybe first 4 digits are representing student number?

Comment: Divide by 100 and cast the fractional and integer parts to ints?

Comment: @moghya first 4 student number, last two is score

Comment: @acraig5075 i was wondering if that was the only way to do it and create new ints from the division? and the remainder to create the other int?

Comment: Another option would be to store the number in a string, devide the string into two strings with the desired number of digits and convert the strings back to numbers

Comment: @AchimGuetlein could you provide an example of how you would do that?

Comment: `id = 288895 / 100` and `score = 288895 - (id * 100)`

Comment: What was the point of that edit?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was adding my edited question, and I realised I updated it without actually adding my further question. Sorry about that, the name change was mainly because my new code decided to use employee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at using the mod (`%`) operator. `288895 % 100` gives `95`, and you can integer divide by `100` so `288895 / 100` gives you the `2888`.